# Getting the whole string with hyperlink in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, string

I have a requirement like I need to show the hyperlink for particular words (Terms and privacy policy), but now I am getting the entire text with underlined. Please find the below code

```
let htmlData = NSString(string: descriptionText).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)
        let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
                NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
     
        
        if let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData  ?? Data(), options: options, documentAttributes: nil) {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.alignment = .left
            style.lineSpacing = Constants.General.lineSpacingVal
           let termsFullRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.sihLegalCopyColor, range: termsFullRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.init(font: .regular, size: 12), range: termsFullRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: termsFullRange)
            termsAndCondText.linkTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.sihLegalCopyColor]
            termsAndCondText.attributedText = attributedString
        }
```

Text String:

```
"En passant et en réglant une commande <a href=\"https://www.subway.com/fr-CA/Legal/order_apptermsofuse\">, vous acceptez les modalités de la politique de confidentialité </a>et <a href=\"https://www.subway.com/fr-CA/Legal/PrivacyStatement-FWH\">relatives à l\'application et à la commande.</a>."
```

NOTE:vous acceptez les modalités de la politique de confidentialité -should not come with underline, but its coming with underline.

[image]

Comment: ", vous acceptez les modalités de la politique de confidentialité " has a HTML link, so it's normal to be "underlined", as it's a link. You want to remove that link? Either you can fix the HTML String (if possible), or you remove the link from the `NSAttributedString` afterwards (but deciding on which one to remove is the question then).